# What does ホルモンの肉が好き mean in this passage?

Tags: translation, meaning

I am a rank amateur at the Japanese language, but I was trying read some articles on the Japanese Wikipedia. I happened to come across the bizarre sentence ホルモンの肉が好き, which looked to me like it said "She likes hormone meat". I ran the passage through Google Translate, and it translated it as "I like the meat of the hormone".

What exactly does this phrase mean, and if it does mean "She likes hormone meat", what am I missing that makes that make sense? Here's the rest of the passage. It's a description of a character from a light novel. It comes from [this Wikipedia page](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%80%88%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E%E3%80%89%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA#.E4.B8.BB.E8.A6.81.E4.BA.BA.E7.89.A9) and is the first paragraph under the section 阿良々木 火憐（あららぎ かれん）. The line in question is the very last sentence:

> 蜂に刺された少女。本格的な初登場は「かれんビー」。「かれんビー」「こよみツリー」のメインキャラクター。中学3年生（「するがデビル」では私立栂の木高校へ進学している）で空手 [注 27]二段の持ち主。暦の2人の妹の内の上の妹で、妹の月火と合わせて「栂の木二中のファイヤーシスターズ」という通り名を持つ。実戦担当で、自称：正義の味方。6月生まれ、身長：170cm（後に175cm以上に伸びている）。自分より背の低い「瑞鳥（みずどり）くん」という年下の恋人がいる（詳細不明だが暦に似ているらしい）。暦曰く「可愛いと言うよりも恰好良い」容姿。ホルモンの肉が好き。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the word is indeed derived from "hormone" ([source](http://gogen-allguide.com/ho/hormon.html)) but in food context refers to dishes [made from offal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horumonyaki).